# scroll normally after the fixed positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/R35LM/1/)

html

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```

css

```
body{  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 101px;    
}
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.one{
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.two{
    background: green;
}
.three{
    background: blue;
    height: 500px;
}
.four{
    background: black;
}
```

**Question:**

When you scroll the blue div is also going to top that is hiding inside the red div one. I want to do this for green div only after then it should scroll normally. That means blue div and from this below all div should not be hidden inside red div.

Is there anyway with jquery. (It would be best if with pure css)

**jQuery:**

I tried the following but something wrong, please suggest how to do?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var toph = 200;
    var scrollh = $(window).scrollTop();
    var totalh = $('.three').height() + $('.four').height();
    if (scrollh == toph){
        $('body').css('margin-top',totalh);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following js function. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JUKBP/1)

```
var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $('.one').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $('.one').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('.one').followTo(100);
```

Comment: the red div should be fixed at top.

Comment: What do you mean that it should be fixed at top? I don't understand your exact problem? Do you have a working example demo of what you need?

Comment: red div must be at top, see my edited question jquery part you may understand.

Comment: Do you want the red div always visible or just keep the red div on top. Updated my demo. Can you check and let me know what need to be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost done, put `position: relative` for `div.three`

```
.three{
    background: blue;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

And for all divs that are not scrolling (can be for example `div.four`,..)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/damoiser/nUwJa/1/

Comment: In your answer it is actually not scrolling. The third div appears on top of first div. Add some text to the first div and test.

Comment: @C-Link to leave the red div on the top you can put a z-index (http://jsfiddle.net/damoiser/nUwJa/5/) but in this case I can't see with jsFiddle if the scroll is done correctly. Do you have a site-link that you are working on it?

Comment: Its even not working in your fiddle. the green div should not go inside the red div

Comment: Your first fiddle is okay for me but in my site its not working. I'm using localhost/

Comment: Okay I got, its a z-index trick. the fixed div is not going to top its stacking in the fixed position but the green div should be z-indexed greater and only feels working. +1 for tricky solution

Comment: @C-Link this is crazy, maybe there are some rule that conflict in production (but I think not, I imagine that dev and production are the same). If you have a public link, give to me, so can I check what is going wrong (but I see that you have find another working solution with jQuery)